# Why not all my Buttons receive the input of the on click in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have developed an application which manages a deck of cards and I need to draw out 3 cards from the deck.
The problem is that only one button is clickable and makes the animations but the other buttons do not receive the click event.

```
//BUTTONS  
     private void setCardsForPlayer(){
        Giocatore giocatoreAttuale = banco.getGiocatoreAttuale();
      if(giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(0)!=null) {         
      buttonCard1.setImageDrawable(giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(0).
      getImmagine() );
           buttonCard1.setOnClickListener(new 
        CardHandler(this,giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(0)));
                }
       else{
          buttonCard1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
      if(giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(1)!=null) {

    buttonCard2.setImageDrawable(giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(0). 
   getImmagine());
           buttonCard2.setOnClickListener(new 
      CardHandler(this,giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(1)));
      }
       else{
          buttonCard2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
      if(giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(2)!=null) {

    buttonCard3.setImageDrawable(giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(2).
  getImmagine());
          buttonCard3.setOnClickListener(new 
 CardHandler(this,giocatoreAttuale.getCartaByIndex(2)));
      }
      else{
          buttonCard3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
  }

//ANIMATIONS FUNCTION
private void muoviCarte(){
    Animation slideInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
 R.anim.move_cards); // THE ANIMATION
    buttonCard1.startAnimation(slideInAnimation);
    buttonCard2.startAnimation(slideInAnimation);
    buttonCard3.startAnimation(slideInAnimation);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because maybe your buttons are not in front of your view, causing them to not being clickable. use this for each button that is not clickable

```
yourButton.bringToFront();
```